# Java - regex for ordinary positive negative number

Tags: java, regex, string, pattern-matching

I read a lot of regex question, but I didn't find this yet..

I want a regex in Java to check whether a string (no limit to length) is a number:

- including negative (-4/-123)
- including `0`
- including positive (2/123)
- excluding `+` (+4/+123)
- excluding leading zero `0` (05/000)
- excluding `.` (0.5/.4/1.0)
- excluding `-0`

This is what I have done so far:

```
^(?-)[1-9]+[0-9]*
```

Comment: Please show us what you've got so far, and we'll help you along.

Comment: Code requests aren't valid questions

Comment: Thanks! - ^(?-)[1-9]+[0-9]*

Comment: sorry, by "exclude +" do you mean 1) do not consider this a legitimate number,  that is, +4 is NOT a number; or 2) do not include the + symbol in the resulting value, that is, +4 is really the number 4?  only the first option makes any sense with the 0.5 example, but it seems odd that these legitimate numbers are being excluded.  do you really mean, determine if the number is an integer?  careful with the terminology, all of those examples are indeed numbers...

Comment: @ryonts excluding the sign +. which make the number +4 illegal:)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The is a optional -

```
-?
```

The number must not start with a 0

```
[1-9]
```

it may be followed by an arbitraty number of digits

```
\d*
```

0 is an exception to the "does not start with 0 rule", therefore you can add 0 as alternative.

Final regex

```
-?[1-9]\d*|0
```

java code

```
String input = ...

boolean number = input.matches("-?[1-9]\\d*|0");
```

Comment: For this kind of answers it was worth building stackoverflow. Detailed, accurate, and demonstrates. You're awesome!!